# updating hash in rails using insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After I Updated rails from 5.1 to 5.2.6

@parent.user_forms.insert(insert_attributes)

error:

```
(byebug) @parent.user_forms.insert(insert_attributes)
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `insert' for #<UserForm::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007fbc89aa6ae8>
Did you mean?  inspect


insert_attributes = {#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x00007fbc9dbd9cd0 @name=....}
```

is the insert method deprecated in rails 5.2, whats is the other alternate I can try?

Already tried:
@parent.user_forms.update(insert_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember `insert` being a method on a collection proxy at all. You can call `insert` on a model class itself (`UserForm.insert(attributes)`) and also `insert_all` (passing an array of hashes).

But you probably need to call `create` on the collection, which merges the association conditions with the attributes. In your case,

```rb
@parent.user_forms.create(attributes)
```

could have the same effect (depending on how the foreign keys are) as

```rb
attributes = attributes.merge(parent_id: @parent.id)
UserForm.create(attributes)
@parent.user_forms.reload
```